# How can I access the data from javascript by Qt?

Tags: javascript, qt, qt4

I used webview to show the webpage,

```
view->setUrl(QUrl("C:\\Qt\\2010.07\\qt\\serbest\\googleSearch.htm"));
```

in the HTML code I put some ajax code googleSearch. After I execute the program, the webview runs and there are results (pages links).

When I clicked any of the links they do not open. So what do I do to open the links I clicked?

How can I access the title of the links from the result of javascript in Qt?

Answer (score 1):

```
"C:\Qt\2010.07\qt\serbest\googleSearch.htm"
```

That's not a URL, it's a Windows pathname. Also, it has troublesome unescaped backslashes: `\201` is a string literal escape for the control character U+0081 in many languages (including JavaScript as per your tags, though the snippet does not appear to actually be JavaScript).

The URL form of that filename would look something like:

```
"file:///C|/Qt/2010.07/qt/serbest/googleSearch.htm"
```

You can convert a filename into a URL using [`fromLocalFile()`](http://doc.trolltech.com/qurl.html#fromLocalFile).